# Updating data in Vector Tiles Leaflet geojson-vt

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

My question is about updating the data in leaflet. 
Let's assume that we have geojson which we are changing into vector tiles using geojson-vt.js and displaying it on the leaflet map. 
Similiary as there: [geojson-vt example](http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/c67e5551b21c68dc8299)

Then i'm receiving an event / notifiaction that some linestring was changed, for example thise linestrings have a attribute color, which is using when displaying data, and this value has changed.

Then i want to update my map, but i dont want to recalculate, and redraw all tiles, but only this tiles where was change. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be done. `geojson-vt` only allows for creating new `geojson-vt` instances, not updating them. Updating data in the internal structures is too complicated, and doesn't give any big advantages. This also means it's not possible to get a list of changed tiles, or even a list of tiles containing the updated geometry.

If this is really critical for your application, consider studying the code for `geojson-vt` for yourself, and proposing a solution.

If you have a set of static features and a set of possibly-changing features, consider making separate holders for them.

Comment: thanks for answer, You give me some idea to find the solution, so i marked Your answer as good